# Unable to create an appropriate selector to scrape some specific links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I've written a script in python using BeautifulSoup to get some specific urls located in the left sided bar available within a chapter titled `VIDEOS BY YEAR` from a webpage. The thing is I can parse those specific urls if i use hardcoded number in my script as I've already demonstrated below. However, my intention is to grab those exact urls without using any hardcoded number in my script. In fact, I'm after any `css selector` to do the same. Hope somebody out there will stretch a helping hand to accomplish this.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html5lib")
for item in soup.select(".woMenuList .woMenuItem a")[-7:]:
    print(item['href'])
```

It produces the below results:

```
/videos/year/2011.htm
/videos/year/2012.htm
/videos/year/2013.htm
/videos/year/2014.htm
/videos/year/2015.htm
/videos/year/2016.htm
/videos/year/2017.htm
```

Html elements within which the urls are:

```
<ul class="woMenuList">

    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2011.htm">2011 (19)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2012.htm">2012 (45)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2013.htm">2013 (29)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2014.htm">2014 (62)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2015.htm">2015 (25)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2016.htm">2016 (46)</a></li>
    <li class="woMenuItem"><a href="/videos/year/2017.htm">2017 (24)</a></li>

</ul>
```

Btw, all the categories and links are within similar type of classes and tags that is why I get stuck. Thanks in advance to take a look into it.

Comment: Can you reword your question or provide some clarification? I'm not quite sure what you're looking for

Comment: Well, I wish to get the same result by kicking out this hardcoded `[-7:]` portion from my script using css selector.

Comment: Could you provide what the output looks like if you remove `[-7:]`?

Comment: That should "just work" without the slice...

Comment: Yeah sure. Check out this link to see what I get as a result when I remove that hardcoded part from my script. [Link_to_the_results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1hncfjlcailvfa/all%20urls.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*=` operator to select only links that contain the string `'/videos/year'`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html5lib")
for item in soup.select(".woMenuList .woMenuItem a[href*='/videos/year']"):
    print(item['href'])
```